# How to implement a button inside a Fragment and have it open a new Activity?

Tags: android, button, fragment

I am new to programming and android dev, I am trying to implement a button inside of a Fragment that will open a new Activity.

I am getting the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' I am also getting the
>   error: Cannot resolve consutructor
>   'Intent(com.hashmi.omar.store.Ip6_Cab,
>   java.lang.Class)'

Below is Ip6_Cab.java:

```
package com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by User on 29/06/2015.
 */
public class Ip6_Cab extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button_ip6_24m_b2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ip6_cab,container,false);
    return v;

    //Sets up iphone 6 button
    button_ip6_24m_b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ip6_24m_b2);
    button_ip6_24m_b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}



private void title_ip6_24m_b2_payment() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Ip6_Cab.this, Ip6_24m_b2_payment.class));
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button_ip6_24m_b2:
            title_ip6_24m_b2_payment();
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the xml layout of where the button that I want the Activity to be opened up from is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="1dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
tools:context="com.hashmi.omar.store.Picker"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:weightSum="1">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

/Image, Bundle and Button 1

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="360dp "
            android:layout_height="267dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/ip6_24m_b1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_ip6_24m_b1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_select_for_bundles"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

/Image, Bundle and Button 2

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="360dp "
            android:layout_height="425dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/ip6_24m_b2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_ip6_24m_b2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_select_for_bundles"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`startActivity(new Intent(Ip6_Cab.this, Ip6_24m_b2_payment.class));` to `getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Ip6_24m_b2_payment.class));`

This is because the startActivity method only exists within a Context and a Fragment does not extend Context. So you need to use the parent activity to start the new activity. Same reason why the first parameter of the Intent class has to be getActivity(), should be a Context.

And you might want to change `button_ip6_24m_b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ip6_24m_b2);` to `button_ip6_24m_b2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_ip6_24m_b2);`

You want to find the view inside the view that you just inflated.

Answer (score 1):

You must find view in your layout. In Fragments you need add your view before `findViewById`.

Also, if you call `return`, method ends in this place. You must call it at the end of method...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ip6_cab,container,false);

    //Sets up iphone 6 button
    button_ip6_24m_b2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_ip6_24m_b2);

    button_ip6_24m_b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;    
}
```

And about starting new Activity, you must:

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Ip6_24m_b2_payment.class));
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Looks like I had misplaced return v;
Both yours and se_bastiaan's answers were correct :D